# Load custom script on a single template

Tags: templates, javascript

So I placed two scripts in the plugin folder, but I can´t figure out why they wont load. I created a custom template where I have placed the following code:

```
<?php
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_register_script('ajax', plugins_url('ajax.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),   'false', 'true' );
wp_register_script('ajax2', plugins_url('ajax2.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), 'false', 'true' );
}
if (is_page_template('page_blankett.php')){
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Multiple issues, fixing one or more of which should resolve the issue:

1. If it's not already, that code should go in `functions.php` and not a template file.
2. Registering the scripts does not actually load them. For that you need `wp_enqueue_script`. If you change your `wp_register_script`s to `wp_enqueue_script`s, that should work.
3. If you need jquery, you should enqueue that too.
4. You want to wrap the calls to `wp_enqueue_script` in the conditional rather than `add_action`. For instance, you might want to enqueue a different script on a different page and could do so within the same function.

Put those all together and you should have this in `functions.php`:

```
<?php
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    if (is_page_template('page_blankett.php')){
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax', plugins_url('ajax.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'),   'false', 'true' );
        wp_enqueue_script('ajax2', plugins_url('ajax2.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), 'false', 'true' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
?>
```

Comment: Don´t I need to register the scripts before I enqueue them?

Comment: Nope. You can enqueue in a single statement like in the example above. If you want, you can also register them like in your example and then just call `wp_enqueue_script('ajax');` but that's really only useful if you need to conditionally load the script multiple times in different scenarios. Otherwise, I tend to just use a straight `wp_enqueue_script()`.